# What does this colon in C# mean

Tags: c#

In this code:

```
var hasManyToOne=false;
foreach(var property in entity.Descendants("Property"))
{
  if (property:manyToOne!=null)
  {
    hasManyToOne=true;
  }
}
```

What does the colon after the variable "property" mean? Is this the same as a period? I can't find any reference in the C# language that shows the colon being used like this.

Comment: Under what C# compiler is that legal?

Comment: i think this is used like ternary operator

Comment: Does this code really compile or you've seen it in a site or an ebook? if that's the case it can be a typo :)

Comment: seems like a typo to me, it could be `property.manyToOne`

Comment: here my understanding is if property has not value then it will check the value of manytoOne and if manytoOne is not null then it will set the value of hasManyToOne to true

Comment: that's the ?? operator

Comment: @Beatles1692 ?? is used when the value **is** null. In this case, the if enters when is not null.

Comment: Please confirm that it is pure c# syntax

Comment: Isn't is some kind of Roslyn hack? What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Its a typing mistake (because `property.manyToOne` is not available in `XElement`) or something else but one thing is sure.

This is not a valid C# syntax and won't even compile. See here.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It means bad code that won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

`:` is not a valid C# operator. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6a71f45d.aspx.

Comment: The fact that is not a valid operator doesn't mean it doesn't exist in the language. Example: `if (1 == 1 ? true : false)` is valid

Comment: @Bart it exists as part of inline if (condition?true part:false part) but not as an independent operator.

Comment: @Beatles1692 OP doesn't even use the Word `operator`

Comment: It is correct that `:` is not an operator. When calling a method and naming the parameters, a colon is used, for example this is legal syntax: `SellItem(price: 9.25m);` You can even put a space before the colon `:` there. That does not make it an operator, of course, but it looks a bit like the code in the original question.